# Connecting two computer via socket, in c and on linux

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have made a sever in C and can comunicate with it via telnet (telnet localhost 8000), it work as intend on my computer.
I would like to work from an other computer, connected on the same network. I tried puting the public ip and host , found on [www.myip.com](http://www.myip.com) in place of the localhost but it didn't work.
here is my sever.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "8000" // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10 // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        ;

    errno = saved_errno;
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in *)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd; // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes = 1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                             p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                       sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");
    while (1)
    { // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1)
        {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                  get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                  s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);
        char myBuff[200];
        if (!fork())
        {
            while (1) {
            memset(myBuff, 0, 200);
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "Hello!\n", 8, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            recv(new_fd, myBuff, 200, 0);
            printf("%s", myBuff);
            }
        }
        close(new_fd); // parent doesn't need this
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The usual:(    You must correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv().  You must ensure that 'string' library calls are passed guaranteed NUL-terminated char arrays.

Comment: 'but it didn't work'......what test failed, and how?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is not with the code itself, but it's more a networking problem...

First of all, I would check that your server is listening on all addresses by running `netstat -ln | grep 8000`. If it returns a specific address (for instance, `192.168.0.176:8000`) then that's the IP that you should connect to. But as you already connected from localhost, I guess that you'll find something like `0.0.0.0:8000` or `*:8000` (I don't remember the exact format now in linux).

If the IP you found is 0.0.0.0 and you want to connect from a computer in the same local network, you shouldn't use the public IP because that's the IP of your router (in fact, you can check that the public IP for both computers will probably be the same because they share the router). Doing it this way is possible but it will most likely require port forwarding so that the router knows to which IP should it send connections attempts for port 8000.

You should execute `ifconfig | grep "inet "` in your server. That will return you a list of the IP addresses the server is listening on. If you execute the same command in the client, you will find at least one of them that is very similar (for instance, `192.168.0.176` in the server and `192.168.0.178` in the client). Then, you should try to use the IP address you found in the server in the telnet command.

If that doesn't work, most likely the firewall in the server is blocking connections to that port in the server. You should try to open that port and check again.

Comment: Thanx you for ansering, i got a I get a "No route to host" error now I thinks it's firewall related